# Configuring RabbitMQ consumer as windows service

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I am looking in for the best way to implement the RabbitMQ consumer by using .Net Client which should be run as windows service.

I referred the RabbitMQ documentation and found the way to consume messages by using .Net client (https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html).

My current scenario is like, RabbitMQ is installed in AWS VM machine. I have to install dotnet client consumer service resides in On-premise network which should consume messages.

Which one is the best way, to always listen the Queue (AMQP protocol) or HTTP API which should get messages on demand (https://pulse.mozilla.org/api/).

Please advise.

Thanks,
Vinoth

Comment: You might try narrowing your question down a bit- exactly what is it that you are having questions about?

Comment: edited the description

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer is "neither." You should have your message queue as a back-end service behind the firewall, and expose your application functionality through a set of carefully-specified web services. The web services, which are exposed through the firewall but can communicate to services behind the firewall, would produce messages that would be transmitted to the server.  Any services needing to produce or consume messages would need to do so via the web services, which would perform safety/security checking prior to forwarding the request on to the AMQP server.

If you need to expose AMQP directly to clients (i.e. that is the purpose of your app), then the recommendation is to do so via [STOMP](https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html).  I think a valid use case for exposing AMQP directly over the internet would be a rare thing to come across.  The security implications of doing so would be immense.

Comment: As you suggested, I am going to create a web services to consume messages and exposed via secured layer. Thanks

Comment: @theMayer :  you mean write a web service that can be running consumer that feeds the web service in return?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz yes.